# Drools: Embedding Workbench in another web application

Tags: drools

I need to embed my drools workbench  in another web application. Following the [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/7.10.0.Final/drools-docs/html_single/index.html#_wb.embedding), I added workbench link in an iFrame in my web app. But on taking the app page I am getting error `Refused to display 'http://localhost:8080/jbpm-console/kie-wb.jsp?standalone&perspective=LibraryPerspective' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.`

how can I embed workbench in another website?

The Drools workbench is running in localhsot:8080 and my web application is in localhost:9090.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the fix for the issue after searching various forums. Modified the wildfly configuration file `standalone.xml` inside docker container.

Added following lines under `<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:undertow:4.0">`

```
<filter-ref name="xFrameOptions"/>

<response-header name="xFrameOptions" header-name="X-Frame-Options" header-value="ALLOW-FROM http://localhost:8090"/>
```

Restarted container, now JBPM workbench is getting in iFrame